# Optional Parameter not being recognised

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Rather than having two API Methods, one to get all entities and get a single entity by an ID. I want to merge these two together as its only one line of code that changes (The lambda to execute). So I thought I may as well make one GET method with an optional parameter and a simple IF statement to determine if the parameter is different from 0.

When I just do a simple GET request I get all of my entities no problem, however upon passing a ID on the end of the URL it is not being recognised when I go to debug the code.

My URL looks like (Service is a Virtual Directory)

```
http://localhost:55985/Service/api/Operator/5
```

Is this a routing issue?

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**GET Method**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int machineID = 0)
    {
        using (DAL.Repositories.Repository<MachineOperators> machineOperatorRepo = new DAL.Repositories.Repository<MachineOperators>())
        {
            try
            {
                var operators = machineOperatorRepo.GetAll(y => y.Machine, z => z.Operator).Where(x => x.Operator.Active && x.Machine.Active);

                if (machineID != 0)
                {
                    operators = machineOperatorRepo.GetAll(y => y.Machine, z => z.Operator).Where(x => x.Operator.Active && x.MachineID == machineID);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I was using [HttpGet] above the method, but since removed it.

Comment: Can you show your method as well?

Comment: Nope, just the default ones at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change method signature to `public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)` because `{id}` can not find in your method

Comment: Exactly the problem, I knew it would have been something silly. Sometimes its only an extra pair of eyes to find a mistake that you become blind to. Thanks :)